# Suggestion for Drupal Staging?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, staging

I need a reference about staging on **Drupal 7**.

My requirements are:

- Content Administrator can perform editing of content in **STAGING** instance
- Can **preview** the changes **without impacting the PROD server** that visitor sees
- Only when the admin says "**DEPLOY/PUBLISH**", the changes are pushed to PROD

Any suggestion about what module should I use? Thank you.

Comment: try http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Why should this be a module at all?

Staging should be a different deployment with a separate database and url.

If you've crossed that option out because you haven't found a way to move across "build" information stored within the database, then look at the [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a solution like that ready, you could try making something with the domain module where content administrators can publish only in staging domain and the admins can publish to all domains. http://drupal.org/project/domain

Edit: to elaborate further, admins could go to the node list and choose which nodes to publish into production, or edit the node and change the domain where that node is publishes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to provide the ability to administrator to edit content without impacting live content, you can use the revisioning module : http://drupal.org/project/revisioning

No need for a separate staging server for that, it's the purpose of a cms after all.